# Get live wordpress images on staging with url change global

Tags: jquery, wordpress, migration

I need setup a local staging from a live wordpress site. Live site containts over 200K images.

My idea is put JS that changes file path all images src that containts a upload folder.

For example:

Live: `http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/roll-up-250x250.png`

Dev: `http://www.localhost/project/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/roll-up-250x250.png`

Is there a any way to do that. This need be done only images that is on uploads folder not for themes design files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with JavaScript by looping through the image `src` values, testing if it's in the '/wp-content/uploads/' directory and if so doing a string replacement for the domain.

```
// this is the pattern we match against
var regexPattern = "/wp-content/uploads/";
// turn the pattern into a regular expression
var regExp = new RegExp(regexPattern);
// get an array of the images
var images=document.querySelectorAll('img');
// loop through each array item
[].forEach.call(images,function(img){
    // test if the src matches the pattern of containing '/wp-content/uploads'
    if(regExp.test(img.src)){
        // replace the test domain with the live domain
        img.src=img.src.replace('www.localhost/project','www.example.com');
    }
});
```

There's probably a more elegant way of doing the matching but I purposefully used regex in an overly verbose way so that this code could very easily be extended into a simple to use function.

P.S. I just ran this in the JavaScript console in Chrome to test it but it could quite easily be included in a MU-plugin file and `echo`d out into a `<script>` on the page.

Comment: @Foxsk8 glad to be of assistance. I actually have this same problem sometimes myself and was never really motivated to fix it until I ready your question. Glad I did though because now I have this snippet to reuse in my own projects :)